# android dev {Intent}

Tags: java, android

```
 public void sendCustomIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.examole.intentnbroadcast.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        intent.putExtra("message", "Custom Intent Test");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Hi, i'm a begineer in android dev.
I try to use image button to connect this method but i can't totally understand this code.
I click the button of this method but nothing happend, can someone explain it to me, thanks!!

Now, i'm not sure the code of this, what's its functionality?

```
intent.setAction("com.examole.intentnbroadcast.CUSTOM_INTENT");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The purpose of a broadcast is to alert other apps or services of certain events. You wouldn't see this code do anything unless you register a `BroadcastReceiver()` to listen for the broadcast `"com.examole.intentnbroadcast.CUSTOM_INTENT"`. Read the broadcast guide here to understand and use broadcasts: [Broadcast overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#:~:text=Android%20provides%20three%20ways%20for%20apps%20to%20send,in%20the%20same%20app%20as%20the%20sender.%20).

Comment: The line `intent.setAction("com.examole.intentnbroadcast.CUSTOM_INTENT");` specifies the intent you're sending, where apps will need to add a `BroadcastReceiver` and intent filter in their manifest and a `BroadcastReceiver` in their code to receive your intent and `"message"`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano But i still some confuse about "CUSTOM_INTENT", what this method do and what it means?

Comment: The "CUSTON_INTENT" is just a name that the user specified for their custom action in 'setAction()'. For instance, if you wanted to define an action that opens another app that you've made, you can have an intent.setAction() that has a string `"com.example.broadcast.OPEN_MYAPP"`. setAction() defines the action to perform. You can then do what I previously mentioned to catch the intent in another app by its action. If you'd like to know more about intents and actions check this: [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thank you so much!! I totally understand it!!!!!